# Most efficient way of evaluating a bool of all items in a vector of <Classtype*>, then returning true if all are true

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector of pointers to class instances I created with multiple values in it called Record
it has a value called, when I access them I

`bool recordDeleted;` 
`bool recordOwnership;`

```
vector<Record*> RecordsVec
```

I want to create a function that would do something like,

```
bool func()
{


    for (auto it = RecordsVec.begin(); it < RecordsVec.end(); it++)
    {
       // check whether recordDeleted is true // or recordOwnership == true)



    }
    // if all are true
       // return true
       // else
       // return false
}
```

what is the most efficient way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple:

```
bool allDeleted() {
    return std::all_of(begin(RecordsVec), end(RecordsVec), [](Record *r) {
        return r->recordDeleted;
    });
}
```

And the same for your ownership flag, of course.

Comment: I assume I could do then,   if (allDeleted() == true || allOwned() == true) { return true;

Comment: @RNewell122 Of course. Why not? Better: `return allDeleted() || allOwned()`.

Comment: Good point, I forget its better practice and C++ default to check if its true .